# Каким образом проверять введенные данные

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь сделать поле ввода, вводя в которое первые буквы, всплывает список с подсказками, из имеющегося массива слов. И если введенное слово есть в массиве, кнопка submit становится активной и можно отправить форму.
Это уже реализовал(общими усилиями) - https://jsfiddle.net/f67v76mb/

```
$("#tags").keyup(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC"
    ];

    if(availableTags.indexOf($(this).val()) == -1 ) {
      $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
    }

    $("#tags").autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
});
```

Но в данном решении, если выбрать слово из всплывающего списка, кнопка активной не становится, нужно обязательно вводить слово целиком + учитывает регистр почему-то.

Буду очень благодарен за любую полезную информацию.
С ajax, js работаю очень редко...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё верно, у вас проверка вхождения элемента в массив выполняется по событию `keyup` - ввод текста в поле, по событию выбора значения в меню у вас ничего и не должно происходить сейчас.

В jquery UI Autocomplete есть событие `close`, которое сработает при закрытии меню с подсказками(когда мы выберем какой-либо пункт - меню закрывается) - можно проверять наличие элемента в массиве по нему.

По второму вопросу - тоже всё верно `indexOf`, как и в целом js чувствителен к регистру. Соответственно можно создать еще один массив, в котором все элементы перевести в верхний регистр при помощи функции `toUpperCase` и, при вводе или выборе значения сравнивать значение поля с элементами нового массива, предварительно так же переводя его(значение поля) в верхний регистр

```js
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC"
];

var availableTagsUpperCase = availableTags.map(function(value) {
  return value.toUpperCase();
});

function checkTags(){
 if(availableTagsUpperCase.indexOf($("#tags").val().toUpperCase()) == -1 ){
    $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
  }else{
    $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
  }
}

$("#tags").keyup(function(){
  checkTags();
});

$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags,
  close: function() {
    checkTags();
  } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="tags" id="tags" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" disabled />
```